# When ${t(s), n(s)}$ is an orthonormal basis, then $DN_p(t) = \pm \tau n$

Tags: differential-geometry

[image: (s)]
The answer to question two tells us that the result of Part 1 implies that $N(s) = \pm b(s)$ Why is that the case? Why can we pick the $N(s)$ vector to be the binormal vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not actually need the information of the second part. Part 1 is true because the curve is asymptotic. If $\bf{t}$ and $\bf{n}$ span $T_pS,$ then ${\bf{t}},{\bf{n}}\perp N.$ However, ${\bf{t}},{\bf{n}}\perp {\bf{b}},$ so ${\bf{b}}\ \|\ N.$ Since all of these have magnitude $1$, we must have that ${\bf{b}}=\pm N.$

Comment: could you ellaborate why $\mathbf{b} || N \implies \mathbf{b} = \pm N$?

Comment: The first thing means that one is a scaled version of the other (collinear). Since they both have magnitude $1$, then means that the constant must be $\pm 1.$

Comment: Recall that they're all unit.